# Is it possible somehow to transpile ES6 to ES5 inside .php files?

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am relatively new with `ES6` and I have a large PHP project where all `view` pages are `.php` files. Almost all files have it's own `JS` code, and I was wondering if it is possible somehow to write `ES6` features inside those files, for example:

```
<body>
   <?= $this->username ?>
   ...
<script>
    const sum = (n1 = 0, n2 = 0) => n1 + n2
</script>
</body>
```

I know some browsers can interpret it (Chrome etc), but others can't (Internet Explorer).
There is any way to transpile `ES6` to `ES5` inside these files or should I write `ES6` features in a separated `.js` file and then transpile it?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to include JS with the HTML anyway, so you might as well separate the code into different files and transpile them. No need to make your life even harder by trying to change the .php files.